# Set Lightning Input Value in Lightning App Builder

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I have added the possibility for admins to set Text Color from App Builder :

```
this.template
.querySelector("lightning-card")
.style.setProperty("--sds-c-card-text-color", this.textColor);
```

In XML I have :

```
 <property name="textColor" type="String"/>
 <property name="number" type="Integer"/>
```

The above works. I now want admins to be able to edit "number" from App Builder as well :

```
this.template
.querySelector("lightning-input")
.value.setProperty("input", this.number);
```

This is the HTML :

```
<lightning-input type="number" name="input"/>
```

I receive an error message that value.setProperty is not a function. Perusing the doc I do not find anything relevant. Is this the right approach ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a normal input field, just set value directly:

```
this.template.querySelector('lightning-input').value = this.number
```

Or, you can bind that value directly to the input:

```
<lightning-input type="number" value={number}></lightning-input>
```

Comment: Thanks ! it worked.